# setInterval and setTimeout hoisting from inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I wrote a simple script to log someone out after a bit of time. I am running into a readonly issue with JS Hint that i'd like to solve but I'm a bit stuck. Is there anything I should change in my script to allow the return of my 2 timeout functions and 1 interval function? Ideally I'd like to get them away from being globals, but I cant think of a way to hoist them up to be accessible inside my rest.

Thanks!

```
var timeOut = {
    time: "2700000",                // in ms (45 mins)
    time_alert: "30000",            // in ms (30 seconds)
    init: function(){
        $("#modal_timeout").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
            timeOut.reset();
        });

        var timeout_Countdown = (timeOut.time/1000) - 1;

        timeOut_display = setInterval(function(){
            $("#modal_timeout span.timeoutCountdown").text(timeout_Countdown);
            timeout_Countdown = timeout_Countdown-1;
        },1000);

        timeOut_timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $(".topmenu #logout").trigger("click");
        },timeOut.time);

        timeOut_alerter = setTimeout(function(){
            $("#modal_timeout").modal();
        },timeOut.time-timeOut.time_alert);
    },
    reset: function(){
        clearTimeout(timeOut_display);
        clearTimeout(timeOut_timer);
        clearTimeout(timeOut_alerter);
        timeOut.init();
    }
};
```

Comment: What “readonly issue with JS Hint” are you referring to?

Comment: That "timeOut_display" "timeOut_timer" and "timeOut_alerter" are: Read Only. This is because they are globals, but ideally I'd like them not to be, just cant think of a way to hoist them up?

Comment: Make those variables properties of the main `timeOut` object instead of globals

Comment: Just as you were writing this, it clicked and I tried that - works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ever look at something too long, and miss the obvious answer? Thanks to @charlietfl as well.

I had to make my 3 functions properties of the main timeOut:

```
var timeOut = {
    time: "2700000",                // in ms (45 mins)
    time_alert: "30000",            // in ms (30 seconds)

    timeOut_display: "",
    timeOut_timer: "",
    timeOut_alerter: "",

    init: function(){
        $("#modal_timeout").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
            timeOut.reset();
        });

        var timeout_Countdown = (timeOut.time/1000) - 1;

        timeOut.timeOut_display = setInterval(function(){
            $("#modal_timeout span.timeoutCountdown").text(timeout_Countdown);
            timeout_Countdown = timeout_Countdown-1;
        },1000);

        timeOut.timeOut_timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $(".topmenu #logout").trigger("click");
        },timeOut.time);

        timeOut.timeOut_alerter = setTimeout(function(){
            $("#modal_timeout").modal();
        },timeOut.time-timeOut.time_alert);
    },
    reset: function(){
        clearTimeout(timeOut.timeOut_display);
        clearTimeout(timeOut.timeOut_timer);
        clearTimeout(timeOut.timeOut_alerter);
        timeOut.init();
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Of course you can kill an interval or a timeout by his name, if defined.

But sometimes, we are out of scope, and uncleared intervals are a pain on slow computers.

On this case you can try this: killing all intervals by their pid.

Following my tests, you might modify the limit, it should be 64000. This number is the maximum interval that a browser can set. it may vary, or evolve! It takes few ms only to iterate, so i don't see it as forbidden way, it works well.

```
function killallIntervals(){
     for (var i = 1; i < 68000; i++)
        window.clearInterval(i); 
 }
```

**Updated with a quick showcase!**

```js
setInterval(function(){ console.log("Interval!") }, 400)
setInterval(function(){ console.log("Another Interval!") }, 700)
setInterval(function(){ console.log("Too much Intervals!") }, 800)
setInterval(function(){ console.log("I want to") }, 1200)
setInterval(function(){ console.log("Die!") }, 1400)


setTimeout(function(){ 
  
  killallIntervals()
  
  console.log("exTerminated!") 
  
  }, 7000)


function killallIntervals(){
  for (var i = 1; i < 68000; i++)     
  window.clearInterval(i); 
}
```

It works to anticipate timeouts too.

Comment: setInterval() would fail only for values larger than 32-bit signed int. The number 2,147,483,647 is the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer.

Comment: There is no ways a browser would set  2,147,483,647  intervals! Trust me it works, it is hacky but functionnal.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, functional value vs actual value. Makes sense they would build some headroom into it as computing power increases. THanks!

Comment: Updated with a demo!